# What is the right way to set a image route in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, localhost, pipe, web-hosting

I'm calling data from a API this includes images but not all of them, so I've created a pipe to handle data without images.

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    @Pipe({
      name: 'noImg'
    })
    export class NoImgPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform(image: any): string {

        if (image === null ) {

          return '/assets/Images/no-img.jpg' ;

          //  Regresa la imagen por defecto no images

        } else {
          return image;
        }
      }

    }
```

here is the file where my pipe points
[image: folder]

It works well in local host but, when I compile the project with `ng build --prod` and host my app the pipe doesn't work.

Also I've activated useHash in the routes and delete the /in the baseHref= ""

Comment: "the pipe does not work" is not very specific. Do you have some errors in the browsers dev-console or network problems for the request?

Comment: remove the leading `/`

Comment: I mean, in production, when I the app is hosted, the doesn't show the no-image.jpg but a classic no images html icon, no errors in the console, it compiles well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should star using / and then the assets folder